# Pointer in ListNode in C

Tags: c, class, pointers, struct

I try to implement a Linked List Node in C++, it wants me to make 'next' as pointer. Why do I have to make 'next' as a pointer , otherwise I will receive incomplete type error from VS ? Why can't I just leave it as a normal variable like 'node next' , then when I point to the next node, I just use 'thisNode->next = nextNode'

```
//C++

struct node{
     int data;
     node * next;
};
or 
class node{
   public:
     int data;
     node * next;
};
```

When I create a node, I also need to make the new node as a pointer.

```
node * newNode;
```

Comment: I have understood nothing.:) Think about what Linked List means. How is it linked?

Comment: @Jabberwocky No, the C declaration of the linked list is wrong.:)

Comment: What is the question here exactly?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow correct, I overlooked this, actually it should be `struct node{
     int data;
     struct node * next;
};`

Comment: Hey thanks for your comments, I remove C part, just focus on C++, I think the manner behind is the same for these two languages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, what I THINK you are asking, is why does the linked list node structure definition have a pointer to another node rather than just including the struct.

First of all you code should declare the pointer to next as `struct node *next` as below.

```
struct node {
   int data;
   struct node *next;
};
```

If instead of a pointer the next field was another node structure, then evey node would contain another node, and that node would contain another note, and so on.  A node struct would be infinately large.  It must be a pointer, and that is the point of a 'linked' list - it links to another node, it does not contain it.

If you declare a struct within another struct, it is literally contained within it.  This is why a recursive struct definition is not allowed.

Comment: Well done for attempting to answer this bizarre question -- you get my vote.  I would add that it's disturbingly common for beginners to mistakenly believe that all pointers must be initialized via a call to `malloc`, and so that may also be a source of the OP's confusion.  Essentially the source of confusion would boil down to your same argument of infinite storage. I suppose you could add detail to the answer, but where would it stop?!  The OP should probably do some reading on basic memory concepts in C, and find extra reference material on linked lists if what they have is insufficient. :)

Comment: Thanks, Euan. I started with implementing Linked List in Java, and Java doesn't have pointer. I want to explore more in other languages. When I implement linked list in JS, and do console.log(theLinkedList) , it displays like a Python dictionary. So one node contains another.  C/C++ is more like a spaghetti of memory management  , so I just try to understand how linked list works in C, C++ . From your explanation , I can understand it seems about properties of C/C++ to avoid infinite self calling.

Comment: @HuyHNguyen Actually, under-the-hood, the other languages will use pointers to point to the contained structures.  For example, when a JS object contains another, that is really a pointer to the contained object, hence why a JS object can have multiple references to it.  `C` is very low level, so you get to see, and have to deal with, the inner workings.  The other languages you mention hide all of these details from you.

Comment: Also, if this answers your question, you should mark it as an answer.

Comment: @HuyHNguyen there are many, many list linked tutorials on the web. Use google to find them. You also need to understand what a pointer is.